# How to access `site.data.header["foo.bar.baz"]` if `foo.bar.baz` is a FrontMatter variable

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want something like:

```
---
my_var: "foo.bar.baz"
---

{{- site.data.header[page.my_var] -}}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work…

I know that I can use `site.data.header.foo.bar.baz`or `site.data.header["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]`, but it's not that.

Also I know that I can split `page.my_var` to substrings and use them then as `site.data.header["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]`. But this increases Jekyll build time.

I guess I need some Ruby plugin, but don't know one and I don't know Ruby to write one.

*If you know such plugin or can help me write one or know some native workaround, this would be sooo great!*

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

> Also I know that I can split page.my_var to substrings and use them then as site.data["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]. But this increases Jekyll build time.

I'm not sure you can do this. And even if you can, I'm not sure that there is a real performance impact.

But you can do this :

**_data/foo.yml**

```
bar:
  baz: 1
  biz: 2
  buz: 3
beer:
  baz: 1
  biz: 2
  buz: 3
```

Then :

```
---
my_var: "foo.bar.baz"
---
{% assign keys = page.my_var | split: "." %}
{% assign object = site.data %}
{% for key in keys %}
  {% assign object = object[key] %}
{% endfor %}
{{ object }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are hoping to do has been blocked by design.

`site.data["foo.bar.baz"]` implies that you need to have a data file named `foo.bar.baz.yml` or `foo.bar.baz.json`, ... etc.

But Jekyll *sanitizes* data files' names and therefore the resulting object would only have a key named `"foobarbaz"`

A plugin that purposely removes this sanitization can written but it wouldn't appear to be a benign or safe to end-users. So the chances of finding such a plugin in the wild *is slim..*